# Dropdown using codeigniter is not dropping any data

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code i have placed the controller ,model and view part.My aim is to drop exam name from exam table.In my case it is drop the exam name from exam table.Pls help me o do this .
Controller

```
public function index()
{   
    //echo "inside form upload";   

    $data = array();
    //$college_name = $this->session->userdata('college_name');
    if($query = $this->import_model->get_exam_data())
    {
        $data['exam_data'] = $query;
    }
    //$this->load->view('student_view', $data);

    $this->load->view('form_upload');
}
```

model

```
function get_exam_data()
{
    //$this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("CONCAT(exam_name, ' ', month,' ',year) AS fullexamname", FALSE);//this will concat the value
    //$this->db->where('college_name',$college_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('exam_table');
    return $query->result();
}
```

view

```
<?php 
    $data = array();
    $data["Select Exam Name"] = "Select Exam Name"; 
    foreach ($exam_data as $row)
    {
        $data[$row->fullexamname] = $row->fullexamname; 
    }
    echo form_dropdown('exam_name', $data, 'small', 'class="dropdown_class"  id="exam_name_id" ');
?>
```

*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `$data` to your view file from controller

```
$this->load->view('form_upload',$data);
```